# How move the fake cursor randomly?

Tags: javascript, cursor

I want to have 2  fakes cursors, i tried this one for creating 2 cursors.

```
// get the fake cursor by is id
var xyMirror = document.getElementById('fakeCursor');
var xyMirror2 = document.getElementById('fakeCursor2');
// listen for mouse movements
window.onmousemove = function(event) {  
// get the user's mouse position
var X = event.clientX;
var Y = event.clientY;
// get the browser window dimensions
windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
// create an inversion of the mouse X, Y position
// subtract mouse X position from window width
// subtract mouse Y position from window height
var fakeX = windowWidth - X;
var fakeY = windowHeight - Y;

// use those numbers to update the fake cursor position
xyMirror.style.top = fakeY+'px';
xyMirror.style.left = fakeX+'px';
xyMirror2.style.top =  10  + fakeY+'px' ;
xyMirror2.style.left =  20 + fakeX+'px'; 
}
```

now their movement depend on original cursor, 
my question is 
How can move them **randomly**?

Comment: `Math.random`? `setInterval`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox no i think that i should use something like time

Comment: What do you mean when you say "like time"?!

Comment: @evolutionxbox something tha doesn't depend on my original cursor, i want that the fake cursor moves Independently

Comment: Yes. My original suggestion will help with that goal.

Comment: @evolutionxbox when i use Math.random the cursor moves to fast

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136888/discussion-between-evolutionxbox-and-parik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some thing like that

```js
// get the fake cursor by is id
var xyMirror = document.getElementById('fakeCursor');
var xyMirror2 = document.getElementById('fakeCursor2');
xyMirror.style.position = "absolute";
xyMirror2.style.position = "absolute";
var xMax = 0;var yMax = 0;
// listen for mouse movements
window.onmousemove = function(event) {  
 // Use event X and Y to set max value
 if (event.clientX > xMax) xMax = event.clientX;
 if (event.clientY > yMax) yMax = event.clientY;
 // Random position for fakeCursor
 xyMirror.style.left = getRandomArbitrary(0, xMax) +'px';
 xyMirror.style.top = getRandomArbitrary(0, yMax)+'px';
 // Random position for fakeCursor2
 xyMirror2.style.left = getRandomArbitrary(0, xMax) +'px';
 xyMirror2.style.top = getRandomArbitrary(0, yMax) +'px';
}

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
 return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```html
<div id="fakeCursor">fake1</div>
<div id="fakeCursor2">fake2</div>
```